# How do I write a summation series in Python for a 2D function?

Tags: python, math

I am trying to write a multi-variable function in Python that is also embedded in a summation.
This is the equation:

```
F(x, t) = sum[ (1/n) * (-1)^(n-1) * sin(pi * x * n) * e^(-n^2*t) ] from n = 1 to A
```

where A is a defined constant and `F(x, t)` is a 2 dimensional array.

I had a thought about using a while loop but got no where. Does anyone have any idea of what I can do?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to compute a summation. A web search for that will find many resources.

Comment: It only makes sense to sum this function as a single point in time.  If you sum over both x and t each time you'll be calculating the incorrectly over time.  That should be an integral, not a mere sum.  It can't scale as time increases.  You should think about what you need to calculate rather than focusing on the Python code.